# gvim missing menu on arch/xfce

Tags: arch-linux, gvim, xfce

See topic.

```
set guioptions?

guioptions=aegirLtmT
```

The normal tip is to delete `~/.gnome2/Vim`, but this file doesn't exist.

The strange thing is that after installing some plugins, `Plugin` shows as a menu item.

Is my gvim installation on arch borked? I've tried reinstalling, but it doesn't help..

EDIT: Accepted answer is not what I did to solve the issue (see my comment to the answer), but  would hopefully have worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears @simendsjo is missing the file `$VIMRUNTIME/menu.vim`. I'd be happy to give him mine, but I would trust me as far as I could digitally throw me. You can download it from [here](http://vim.cybermirror.org/runtime/menu.vim) though (it's a mirror ftp.vim.org) and place it in `$VIMRUNTIME/`.

I'm only creating a separate answer so others see it as the correct answer if in fact this fixes it.

Comment: I ended up continuing to uninstall everything vim and deleting all settings. This helped. I guess I f.. up when installing some through manual AUR, some through yaourt, and some manually copied from a windows disk :)

Answer (score 3):

I don't have the answer, but here is how I would approach the problem.

The first thing to try would be to start gvim from a shell like this:

```
gvim -u NONE
```

That should show you the menu bar and the tool bar. If you don't see both of those, perhaps your gvim was built without support for them, but that's doubtful. Execute

```
:version
```

and look for any feature names that begin with `-`, such as `-menu`.

It is suspicious that the order of flags in the 'guioptions' value you have shown differs from the default order. That suggests that something removed, then added flags during startup. That might have something to do with it. Restart gvim normally and xecute

```
:verbose set guioptions?
```

to see what touched that option last.

Something else you can try is to execute

```
:scriptnames
```

That will show you all the script files that gvim has sourced since startup. That might show you some suspicious files such as the `~/.gnome2/Vim` you were looking for.

Comment: This is excellent. One more place you should add for them to check is in ``$VIMRUNTIME/menu.vim``. I ran ``gvim --version | grep menu`` and saw that in fact there is a ``+menu`` option and that path came up as the system menu file. So if his is compiles properly, he might just be missing the menu file. Inside of gvim he can determine the value of ``$VIMRUNTIME`` by doing ``:echo $VIMRUNTIME``.

Comment: `-u NONE` doesn't show the menu. Without this option, the `Plugins` menu item appears.
`:version` has both `+menu` and `+toolbar`.
@sigmavirus24: I'm missing menu.vim - it doesn't appear even after reinstalling gvim. What to do...